# Initial startup blank screen

Tags: boot, sd-card, software-installation

So when I say I'm new to raspberry pi, I've got nowhere...

I've taken my raspberry pi model B+ v1.2 out of the box plugged mouse, keyboard, hdmi (monitor) and sd card in. No Ethernet.

I've plugged in the power and all there is, is a black/blank screen. 2 lights on the board but nothing has happened??

I have no instructions or knowledge about these, so I expected the sd card to boot when I turned it on. What have I done wrong? Or is there something wrong the pi board/ sd card. I have purchased?

Edit: my screen says no signal detected and the keyboard appears to have no lights suggesting power.

> EDIT

Could this be the problem?

F.A.Q.s
Hey I just got a Raspberry Pi Model B+ and the USB/Ethernet doesn't work!
Your kernel/firmware (operating system) has to be updated to support the new USB/Ethernet controller chip! The annoying thing is that to upgrade you kinda need network connectivity which you can't get if USB/Ethernet is down. If you have a spare Model B around, try running
sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get upgrade
To update to the latest kernel!

Comment: Hello and welcome. I notice you do not mention the installation of any operation system on the SD card. Did you buy it with a pre-installed system or is it an empty card - which would then require that you [install an OS image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/) to it.

Comment: Assuming it is a quad core Pi 2, this is a duplicate of a duplicate, etc., because the green light on solid is what happens when no SD card, or an invalid SD card, is inserted.  Try taking the card out and plugging the pi in -- exactly the same thing will happen.  If this is not a Pi 2, leave a comment and I will re-open this.

Comment: The box doesn't say anything about 'pi 2' just pi. Model b+ board It and SD card with operating system

Comment: @goldilocks in addition to my last comment, the power cable supplied in the pi box is output 5v and 1.8A. This was supplied by element14 so I presume it's appropriate?

Comment: Okay, all apologies -- but  you do need to be specific and include relevant details when you have a problem.  If it's a B+, say it's a B+.   Last I checked, although the form factor is the same, the B+ is different from the 2 in its behaviour WRT the green light being on steady with no SD card, but... "On" is ambiguous: are they both on solid?  Is the green light flickering, or is the green light flashing in a steady, repeated pattern.  All three are possible and mean different things.

Comment: That power supply should be sufficient, but we do occasionally get people reporting improperly formatted SD cards from distributors.  If the green light flashes irregularly and then settles down after a few seconds and goes off, that's normal,  so you could try adding `hdmi_safe=1` to `config.txt` on the first partition; this will give you the best chance of output if the system is running.  https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#hdmi-mode-options

Answer (score 1):

As ghanima said above, this might be due to the SD card having the operating system installed ([see here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md)). Additionally, are you plugging the HDMI cable in before anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Checklist for you :

- Make sure your power supply is at least 5V and 1A. I've measured RPi during run, no greater power required, but 2+Amp power is a must-have for usage/load
- Try to use USB2COM, and if it's OK via COM port, tweak options in txt config files for HDMI and so forth
- Try a totally headless boot, find it's IP address obtained via *wired* ethernet and see for an error logs

Comment: Power cable is fine, but all other ports are not working. I think my edit may begin to explain the issue.

Comment: @LiamH is your DC input meterd by something like [this](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31iHJT-Lw3L._SX300_.jpg) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you bought a pre-installed sd card then it could be a monitor issue. 
On my machine I should first turn on the monitor and only after that I have to turn on (plug) the PI. 
Also be sure to have your monitor set on HDMI in. Eventually go to the menu page on your monitor to check that.

Comment: Then I suggest to download a new, latest, OS image (Raspbian in my opinion) and flash it on another sdcard (if you have a spare one). You can do it from a regular PC if you have an sdcard reader with usb plug. Just go on the official RPI site. Good luck!